# How can we reference an HTML markup element in an MVC Razor View

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

Using MVC Razor how can we reference an HTML markup element in our view as a template (that can be passed to a helper as a string or object)?

Example of desired functionality (or similar, I prefer a/the standardized approach but I haven't been able to find one):

```
@TemplateOne {
    <!--Standard Razor markup:-->
    <div>
        <p>@Model.Summary</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Lorem ispum...</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Reference by ID:

```
@{
    var templateToPassToHelper = TemplateOne;
}
```

I know that the syntax on the above code is incorrect because its not working on my local tests. The closest I've come to accomplishing this is to use the following (which doesn't answer the question or fix the issue because the variable is just a string and using this approach keeps the dev from being able to use the Visual Studio intellisense and other HTML editing assistance):

```
string template =
  @"<html>
      <head>
        <title>Hello @Model.Name</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        Email: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
      </body>
    </html>";
```

Comment: Are you looking to create your own custom html helper?

Comment: Use `Html.Partial` and have all your razor syntax in the partial view. Stuffing the markup in a string, or using some custom helper completely defeats the purpose of using MVC

Comment: @Code Yes I've created a custom Html Helper. @Brent Mannering Even if I was to use `Html.Partial` the same problem is raised. The purpose of using the "Template" is that the "Template" is defined in the view. Currently we have 96 Views in the Solution and roughly 30 of them have heavily customized (by business rule logic) for this section. This section is one small portion of the rest of the `HTML` (defined currently in the Helper) and must be dynamic. So if this section was passed to a Partial, the section (dynamic template) would need to be referenced and passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do what you are talking about.

Going off of @brent-mannering comment:

Create a razor partial file (_partial.cshtml):

```
<div>
    <p>@Model.Summary</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ispum...</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And then use `@Html.Partial("_partial.cshtml",Model)` in wherever you want the template.

Or you could use a helper function:

```
@helper TemplateOne(){
    <div>
        <p>@Model.Summary</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Lorem ispum...</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
<!--body of your page-->
@TemplateOne()
```

Comment: I believe this second answer will do the trick, going to test then reply to this thread with an update.

Comment: @id.ot: Also note that you can treat that like a function, so you can add parameters to the helper Eg:`@helper TemplateOne(string x, int y)` to customize it if you are using it in multiple places on a page.